# RPC call "svc_fd_create" fails on SOLARIS with "Bad file number" error

Tags: network-programming, solaris, rpc

I'm required to replace some obsolete RPC calls in the base code. I have to replace "svcfd_create()" with "svc_fd_create()". The changes were working successfully on linux, however it is failing on SOLARIS.

I created the following sample program to check the scenario, "svcfd_create()" is working successfully however "svc_fd_create()" fails with the error "socket: Bad file number".

Platfrom:

bash-3.2# uname -a
SunOS XXXXXXX 5.10 Generic_Virtual sun4v sparc sun4v

Command used to compile:

/usr/bin/CC -R/usr/ucblib -L/usr/ucblib -L/usr/lib -lsocket -lrpcsoc -lnsl Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <rpc/svc_soc.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
        register SVCXPRT *transp;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
        int sock;
        int pid;

        sock  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock < 0) printf("ERROR opening socket");

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(2363);

        if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                 sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                 printf("ERROR on binding \n");
        listen(sock,5);

        perror("socket");

        printf("Socket created : %d \n", sock);
        printf("before svc_fd_create \n");
        // Uncomment the line with "svcfd_create" and comment the line with "svc_fd_create" to run success scenario
        //transp = svcfd_create(sock, 0, 0);  // RPC CALL WORKING
        transp = svc_fd_create(sock, 0, 0);    // RPC CALL NOT WORKING
        printf("after svc_fd_create \n");
        perror("socket");
        if (transp == NULL) {
            printf ("cannot create tcp service.\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("transp->xp_fd: %d \n", transp->xp_fd);
        }
}
```

With "svcfd_create", it results in following output:

```
bash-3.2# ./a.out
socket: Error 0
Socket created : 3
before svc_fd_create
after svc_fd_create
socket: Error 0
transp->xp_fd: 3
```

With "svc_fd_create", it results in following output:

```
bash-3.2# ./a.out
socket: Error 0
Socket created : 3
before svc_fd_create
after svc_fd_create
socket: Bad file number
cannot create tcp service.
socket() failed: Bad file number
```

What is missing here to make  "svc_fd_create()" work successfully. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Remove `printf("after svc_fd_create \n");`, as it's likely changing `errno`.

Comment: The error is still the same.